# How to install/use Composer without SSH

Tags: php, composer-php

guys I have a shared hosting and I can't use SSH or call shells  with php (`shell_exec`),for security reasons, I can't upgrade my server for money problems...But i need to install `Composer`, and work with an SDK for finish my project?Is there any way to install/use `composer` without SSH? I have read about install Composer offline, and then upload the contents on the server, but i don't think that this work...
Thanks for read! Hope that you all'll have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As You Said You Want to Install Composer Without SSH then**
In that case you Have to install it in your `local system` than after you can easily `upload` it using `FTP`and its Works if your host is supported !!

---

### Steps For Shared Hosting Using FTP::

- First Download Php Shell From Here: http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/
- In PHPShell's `config.php` Add User & alias:

  `php = "php -d suhosin.executor.include.whitelist=phar"`
- Login to `PHPShell` & Type: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
- After Successfully installed, Just Run Composer: `php composer.phar`

Comment: Thank !! You safe my day