# Composer updates at ftp-only hosting

Tags: php, composer-php

I am working on a project where composer (https://getcomposer.org) is used. My problem is, the destination server is equipped with only FTP access (no shell, ssh, rsync). Each time I run "composer update" or another "require" at my dev machine, I need to upload all the vendor directory. As for now, +16k files are not a big problem yet, but even a small change requires a transfer of relatively huge amount of data.

I have tried to git the vendor directory, and use "git ftp" to deploy only the changed files, but as some libraries are seen as subprojects and/or have their own .gitignore files included - this method doesn't work quite well.

Runnig a script exec("composer update") seems to be not working either. Probably, the "exec" function at the live server is disabled, which on other hand, doesn't seem to be a bad idea on a public server (security issues, to be investigated by me).

I would love to find something like "composer remote synch" or similar method to transfer only the new installed or updated libraries to the remote server (composer.json, autoload.php of course included, but these obvious files are not a problem). Any tips, ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the [PHP Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46612647/3209381) method?

Comment: For the few remaining sites that we have that are FTP-only, we use [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php) to compare our two file system and only move what has changed. Whatever you do, I'd encourage you to run composer with the `--no-dev` option before syncing so remove the `require-dev` portions of things, that should speed some parts up at least.

Comment: Why not use a proper deployment process where all this uploading stuff is done on another machine and does not bother you?

Comment: @NicoHaase well, what do you mean by another machine? I would love to convince my customer to use a full-featured hosting, but I doubt it will happen soon. For now, I'm stuck with what I have. Of course, I was considering some deployment tools like, for example phing, but this does not solves my problem with huge upload. Or at least, I have not found yet any configuration for such tool which would upload only the changed files.